# Parse large csv files java on Android

Tags: java, android, database, parsing, csv

I have a csv file, you need to migrate the database. 
I created a class for its parse and transfer to the database, but is quite slow. 
Import takes about three minutes. Is there any way to make it faster? 
I apologize for my English.
Thanks in advance!

```
final String[] SCANCODES = {"CODEPRODUCT", "SCANCODE"};
dbSync.importCSV(SCANCODES, "SCANCODES.CSV", "SCANCODES");  

////
.....
////

public void importCSV(String[] tableCol, String nameFile, String nameTable) {
        final File DATABASE_DIRECTORY = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImportExport");
        final File PATH = new File(DATABASE_DIRECTORY,"SCANCODES.CSV");
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String s = "";
        boolean skipLines = true;
        String[] data;
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(PATH), "Windows-1251"));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //skip header
                   if (skipLines) {
                        skipLines = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                //- 1 not skip blank
                data = s.split(";", -1);
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; ++i) {
                    cv.put(tableCol[i], data[i]);
                }
                db.insert(nameTable, null, cv);
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                db.endTransaction();
                br.close();
                new Folder().deleteFolder();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT
Added encoding

Comment: You should specify the encoding when opening a `Reader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `bulkInsert` method. It should improve the performance quite a bit.

As far as I understand you are reading that .csv file locally. Instead of reading a .csv file you can ship your APK with a valid `SQLite` database in your `assets` folder and then you can just move the file to the databases folder as described in the below link:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: I have such files, it is a means of exchanging data. They are constantly updated, and I have to enter them every transition. bulkInsert method will try thanks.

Comment: If you get the data online I don't there is no other optimization besides bulkInsert().  You can also do this. Make this long call in background and display a progreassdialog so that the user waits until the operation is done.

Comment: I thought to make the file mapped to memory, but I have data of varying lengths and set the read buffer I can not (
Thanks for the help I will try.